# How to write a nested IF statement that has multiple outputs?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

The context:

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3    Column 4  (IF statement result column)
a,b                   2.99        $2.99     1/2 mismatch     
a          a,b        3.49        $2.89     Column 1/2 mismatch,3/4 mismatch  
b          a          1.99        $2.99     Column 1/2 mismatch,3/4 mismatch
a,b        a,b        3.49        $3.49
```

so only in stance of and exact match (I have many columns that have comparable values that I need to follow this pattern). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may need to add more columns for the question to be nontrivial. As it is currently, it looks like you can just check `[Column 1] = [Column 2]`.

Comment: columns added, does this provide a better picture of the problem?

Comment: is it possible to nest many if statements in a CONACATENATEX()??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need nested `IF` statements, just `CONCATENATEX`:

```
Result =
VAR ColList = { [Column1], [Column2], <...more columns if needed..> }
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX ( FILTER ( ColList, LEN ( [Value] ) > 0 ), [Value], "," )
```

---

**Edit:** The basic approach above can still be used but you'll want to modify what is in your `ColList`.

```
Result =
VAR Pair12  = IF ( [Column 1] <> [Column 2], "1/2 mismatch" )
VAR Pair34  = IF ( [Column 3] <> [Column 4], "3/4 mismatch" )
VAR ColList = FILTER ( { Pair12, Pair34 }, LEN ( [Value] ) > 0 )
RETURN
    "Column " & CONCATENATEX ( ColList, [Value], "," )
```

Or refactored a bit to remove variables:

```
Result =
"Column "
    & CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER (
            {
                IF ( [Column 1] <> [Column 2], "1/2 mismatch" ),
                IF ( [Column 3] <> [Column 4], "3/4 mismatch" )
            },
            LEN ( [Value] ) > 0
        ),
        [Value],
        ","
    )
```

Comment: So the example is a very basic version of the ask, that is why I phrased it in such a manner. I am trying to apply functions to particular values (with blanks present as well) I am comparing columns of similar values with Exact (and if in the corresponding comparative column it doesn't match I need to produce a result and if it matches it can be blank)

Comment: I'd suggest phrasing it in such a way that sufficiently represents your actual question then. I can only answer what I can see, not read your mind.

Comment: understood rephrased question with some more context

Comment: This answer works in only a power query context, thank you. I am looking for a DAX/mcode variant for my answer, a new question has been posted, please do not flag without understanding context (as it is different from the solution that you have presented)

Comment: This is not Power Query. It is DAX.