# USING DAX: How can I get output that are not blank from COMBINEVALUES()?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have several nested IF statements in a COMBINEVALUES(), everything works but I am trying to remove ",,,VALUE,VALUE" the occurrences of blank comma separations so it displays as "VALUE,VALUE".

Any suggestions?

```
COMBINEVALUES(",",IF(,"","VALUE"),IF(,"VALUE",""))
```

is the general example of the code, but is there a way in DAX/M code to do this?

Comment: Why can you not use `CONCATENATEX`? I'm not sure this is possible with `COMBINEVALUES`.

Comment: That is, why is the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960428) not applicable?

Comment: This is using the COMBINEVALUES() with nested IF(), it is quite different than your answer (there are many ways to accomplish the same thing I know, but for this instance is there a way to work with COMBINEVALUES()?

Comment: There's not a way that I can think of. `COMBINEVALUES` simply isn't flexible enough. If there's a workaround I'm not thinking of, it's likely clunkier than the `CONCATENATEX` version I suggested, which handles an arbitrary number of `IF` statements easily.